# Strange url change after open url?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Hello Lords and Ladies

I have an add on for Firefox that opens a url after the tabs opened the url value changes (example later). This happens not when I start my add-on with `jpm run -b Nightly` but in in the normal version (Firefox 49.02). So I guess its a Firefox preference, but I don't know which one I hope you guys can help me.
An url like

```
https://openload.co/embed/8bDT4mINiNs/919_Days_01_GerSub.mp4
```

turns into this

```
data:text/html,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Chtml%20lang%3D%22en-US%22%3E%0A%3Chead%3E%3Cmeta%20charset%3D%22utf-8%22%20%2F%3E%3Cbase%20href%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fopenload.co%2F%22%20%2F%3E%3Cscript%3Ewindow.exclude%3Dtrue%3Bwindow.turnoff%3Dtrue%3Bwindow.useCors%3Dtrue%3Bdocument.addEventListener(%22mouseup%22%2Cfunction()%7Blogpopup(1)%3B%7D...
```

Iam using the developer edition (FF49) version to run my add-on with jpm.

But its not an add-on problem with an without any add-on install its the same behavior the Quelltext of the site moves into the address bar.

The Link i want to open is the src from an iframe.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: How are you installing your add-on? Are you using the unbranded release version (i.e. this would be needed unless your add-on has been signed by Mozilla)?  Have you tried using a completely new/empty/blank profile to check that it is not an issue between your add-on and any other add-on you have installed?

Comment: Its not a addon or code problem. I edited my question

Comment: In prior versions, I have experienced strangeness when running add-ons in the unbranded versions of Firefox.  For example, an add-on which worked when installed on version x.0a1 (Nightly), and x.0a2 (same version, but as Developer Edition), but then did not work on x.0b1 (Unbranded Beta), but then did work on X.0 (once signed, but otherwise unchanged).  As I recall, I did not try the same add-on on the Unbranded release version, when that version was released. Basically, I just gave up on trying the unbranded versions of Firefox.

Comment: Have you tried loading the add-on in *exactly* the same manner on Nightly (with the same profile) as you are trying with the Unbranded Release version?

Comment: oh am using the developer edition I thought that was the Unbranded. i added the complete link maybe you want to try it. Again its not an addon problem if i open the link manuell without any addon installed its the same

Comment: It is not clear to me what is happening.  You have said that the problem does not happen without your add-on installed.  Thus, I'm not clear what benefit there is for me to go to that URL without your add-on installed.